# Make an arrow to point at a direction from UI

Tags: unity

I want to have a guiding arrow on the left side of UI. The arrow is child of the player's camera and it's rendered from another camera into render texture. The render texture is displayed on the screen. The arrow is rotated via `transform.LookAt(targetPosition)` The problem I'm having is that although it does point in the right direction, form player's point of view it looks like the arrow is pointing somewhere else.
[image]
I want that arrow to point from the point where it's placed on the UI. It should look something like this:
[image]
I tried to do this:
  `Vector3 direction = targetPosition - _arrowRawImage.rectTransform.position;
_transform.LookAt(direction);`
but it didn't work.

Comment: It's a bit hard to say what is wrong without seeing what your camera is recording exactly. Could you post images of what the arrow camera is rendering? Also as a side note, are you sure you want to use a separate render texture for something as simple as the arrow? Most people do recommend using render textures like this for UIs but personally I like just changing the material to skip depth testing and just render over everything. If you do it that way you can just have your main camera render the arrow and remove it from the UI.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the `_arrowRawImage.rectTransform.position`, which is getting the *vector* of the raw image and not the arrow itself. Try working with the position of the arrow transform.

```
Vector3 direction = (targetPosition - _arrowTransform.position);
_arrowTransform.LookAt(direction);
```